# Are effervescent tablets same as efficient as tablets?

Tags: medications, supplement

For example if I take a effervescent calcium does it have the same effect as a calcium tablet?

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27540208 this small study compares the differences between effervescent tablets and liquid suspension but I suspect this question is too broad as the structure of supplements varies massively.

Comment: As above, and also a clarification: is the question asking about the effervescence property itself, or about liquid suspension vs tablet?

Comment: I am asking, which choice should I make to get most of It's properties? tablet or effervescent tablet?